# Connecting UITextField to update a label

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I'm still working on my converter app, and I have once again stumbled across a problem.

While trying to make all edits in the text field to trigger the calculation code, not a single thing happens. This is what happens atm:

[image: trying to enter numbers]

The calculation will not trigger until I change something in the PickerWheel. Which I'm not blaming the code for, as thats how I first made it.

While trying to fix this, I got some help from a buddy, and I added following code to make it work.

First,

```
- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self updateConversionLabel];
}
```

in the beggining of .m, and the following in .h (I know its two, and thats probably wrong, but i wanted to try both.)

```
-(IBAction)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField;
-(void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField;
```

The calculation is as follows:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
[self updateConversionLabel];
}

- (void)updateConversionLabel
{
float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];

float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];

float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
float to = convertTo;
float from = convertFrom;

float convertValue = input;
float relative = to / from;
float result = relative * convertValue;

NSString *convertFromName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *convertToName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]];



NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %.4f %@",result, convertToName];
resultLabel.text = resultString;

NSString *formelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %.4f %@=", convertValue, convertFromName];
formelLabel.text = formelString;


}
```

I figured the error could be in interface builder, so here is the connections
[image: connections inspector]

Is there a simple solution for this? :)

Comment: If you add a log before you are setting your label.text value is that log being output in your console?

Comment: If you ment here, it did not output. 

        
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                              @" %.4f %@",result, convertToName];
    NSLog(@"Test");
    resultLabel.text = resultString;

Comment: @propstm Is that a bad sign? :P

Comment: No log statement means that we're not even seeing the code get into the updateConversionLabel method.  Add a log to picker didSelectRow and make sure that is triggered.  You're going to want to update your values both when the picker changes as well as when the textfield changes like Edwin mentions below to make sure you have the textfield delegate implemented as well.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. The problem is connection the code (as seen above) to the stuff in the interface builder. @propstm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the action "Value Changed", use "Editing Changed" for a text field.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view controller conforms to UITextFieldDelegate. Set the viewController as the delegate of your UITextField in interface builder. Then implement this delegate method in your viewController:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

That delegate method gets fired every time you make changes to the textfield so trigger your calculation in there.

Comment: i'm sorry, this did not help me very much. Can you please explain further? Where should I put this code? I dont have a delegate for the text field, do I need this? I think its not so complicated at all, just a quick fix with the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your textFieldChanged action to 'Editing Changed' and put all of your calculation code in the textFieldChanged action method.

Comment: soz mate, u were 2 late 4 da free rep